# how i can count lat and lon in radius ten or twenty kilometres from center

Tags: math, geolocation, geometry, radius

I need count random lat and lon in radius 10 and 20 kilometres from center, which cords i have.

For example:

```
    location_center = {
            "lat": 5.0123,
            "lon": 40.712
}
```

Random cords in radius 10 km:

```
    location_center = {
        "lat": 6.246,
        "lon": 45.678
```

}

Random cords in radius 20 km:

```
    location_center = {
        "lat": 7.368,
        "lon": 50.678
```

}

How i can count it?

Will be grateful for the help.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "count" here. Also, latitude and longitude aren't dependant on the size of a sphere, they're angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate random angle in range 0..2*Pi

Using `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point` section from [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), calculate point at needed distance `d` in km (with earth radius `R=6378.13 km`)

```
brng = random() * 2 * Math.pi
lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                  Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1),
                        Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```